# Не загружается изображение html

Tags: html5

```html
<div class="col-md-2 logo">
   <img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

изображение не загружается, директория правильная, название файла и расширение тоже. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас относительный путь, вы уверены, что путь у вас правильный? Попробуйте задать ссылку относительно корня сайта, например `/images/logo.png`, или же полный путь, с доменом `example.com/images/logo.png`. Не знаю ваш уровень знаний, поэтому объясню поточнее. `../` означает, что нужно искать в каталоге ниже. Например, `/asd/dfg/../fgh.png` то же самое, что и `/asd/fgh.png`

Comment: Файл загружаю с диска. Путь задавала всеми возможными способами, результат тот же.

Comment: @Ekaterina то есть, он должен подгружаться из файловой системы? Поставь простенький файловый сервер, чтобы все было хорошо, ну или xampp, или denver.

Comment: попробовала загрузить другое изображение, по такому же пути, загрузилось, все остальное не грузит

Comment: а расширение img - png?

Comment: @Ekaterina попробуй почистить кэш браузера.

Comment: @Ekaterina И, кстати, да, возможно расширение изображения не .png

Comment: расширение png у обоих. Очистила кэш, все получилось. В первый раз с такой проблемой столкнулась) Спасибо!

Comment: браузер какой - Хром?

Comment: @soledar10 мозила